# Node large data processing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 500 mongodb databases and i need to connect all the databases and check record in collection based on condition and then record.

One approach is to use for loop and manipulate database like this one:

```
for(var i=0; i<databases.length;i++){
 //connect to database
 //find query
 // add record to array

}
```

It will work fine but take a long time. Is there any other way to do fast processing in optimizes way ?

Answer (score 1):

At a bare minimum, you could run more than one query at the same time.

Look at this:

http://www.sebastianseilund.com/nodejs-async-in-practice

> I need to iterate over a collection, perform an asynchronous task for each item, but only let x tasks run at the same time, and when they're all done do something else

So, your code could become something like:

```
var results =[];

async.forEachLimit(databases, 5, function(database, callback) {
     //connect to database
     //find query
     //add record to array - results.push(result)
}, function(err) {
    //handle error here
});
```

This will be running 5 concurrently... not sure what the maximum number of outbound connections would be.

Comment: Internally Async is doing the same thing, it will take the same time.

Comment: @Rohit, no, that's not right - async.forEachLimit example I gave you will execute 5 of them at the same time - your synchronous for loop will do one, wait for that to complete, then move to the next